# How to remove and return array list index

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to remove and return the object at the first index of my array list called deck. My code returns the object at index 0 post remove() being called, so it's always returning the second index of the original deck array list. I'm not sure how to return the index at 0, THEN remove it.

```
public Card dealCard()
{
    int i = 0;                
    Card topCard = null;
    if(deck.size() > 0)
    {
        topCard = deck.get(i);
        deck.remove(topCard);        
    }           
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Fatal Error. Program now exiting.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return topCard;
}
```

Comment: Does it return the 0th obj when you comment "deck.remove(topCard); " ?

Comment: It looks correct to me.  What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it returns the 0th object when remove() isn't in play

Comment: It's wrong because it is returning the element at index 0 AFTER remove() is called, instead of returning the index at 0 of the original array list, THEN removing it.

Comment: No.  `topCard = deck.get(i)` sets `topCard` to the card that was the i'th prior to being removed, then `deck.remove(topCard)` removes that card from `deck` but doesn't change `topCard`.

Comment: I believe that as well, so I'm not sure why my output is different when I utilize remove()

Answer (score 1):

[`remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) returns the element at `index` when you pass an index to it. So all you have to do is

```
if(deck.size() > 0)
{
    topCard = deck.remove(i);
}
```

This will set `topCard` to whatever is at index `i` and remove the element from the list

Comment: This still returns the first index after remove() is called, so it's missing the index 0 of the original deck array list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Card dealCard()
{
    int i = 0;                
    Card topCard = null;
    //topCard.equals(deck.get(i));
    //deck.remove(topCard);
    if(deck.size() > 0)
    {
        topCard = deck.get(i);
        deck.remove(i);
        //temp = deck.remove(topCard);
        //temp.equals(deck.remove(topCard));           
    }           
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Fatal Error. Program now exiting.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return topCard;
}
```

Comment: Still causing same issue unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Sorry, new here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove what you store in the variable top card, instead remove the item by its index.

> ```
> public Card dealCard() {
> int i = 0;                
> Card topCard = null;
> if(deck.size() > 0)
> {
>     topCard = deck.get(i);
>     deck.remove(i);        
> }           
> else
> {
>     System.out.println("Fatal Error. Program now exiting.");
>     System.exit(0);
> }
> return topCard;
> ```

Comment: Still causes same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Item from list using index

```
deck.remove(i);
```